# Create Images from EC2 instance based on tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have created an environment in AWS and configured all the instances. We have the instances tagged with `NAME` and `ENVIRONMENT` tags.

We would like to **make images of all the instances tagged with a specific `Environment` tag**.  I'm able query the environment with `aws ec2 describe-instances --query` and pull the tags (ex, `Environment=TEST`), but can't figure out how to proceed from here so that all instances with the environment tag `TEST` can be imaged programmatically.

This was the command I used to pull the `NAME` and `ENVIRONMENT` tag info:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations\[*\].Instances\[*\].{Name:Tags\[?Key=='Name'\],Environment:Tags\[?Key=='Environment'\]|\[0\].Value,Status:State.Name}"  --filters "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running"
```

Comment: You'll also need the InstanceId, then you can use `awscli ec2 create-image` to capture an AMI, instance by instance.

Comment: proceed with create-image command, feeding it with instance ID in loop. ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-image.html